# How delete fiction second display?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display

After I load from USB Ubuntu 20.04 the computer identified 2 displays but I have one. The second display was primary and after reboot every time becomes primary. On my physical display only the wallpaper shows. I should Right Click Mouse -> Display Settings and make the primary physical monitor:

[image: screenshot with two versions of desktop on screen and settings showing "primary display" and 2 screens]

My hardware:
i7-2600, 24gb ddr3, NVidia GTX 550Ti, AMD Radeon RX 550, Z68XP-UD4. (If I take away video adapters, nothing changes.)

Maybe I don't know something, this is my first Linux experience.